# С ошибка при выполнении free()

Tags: c, отладка, memory-management

Все привет. Имеется маленькая програмка на C. Выполняет форматирование HTML разметки, пока что не полностью. Вот сам код.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

#define SIZE_OF_STR 1024
#define SIZE_OF_ARR_COL 128

char **div_format(char **s);

// <div> cheburashka <div> pozdno el kofe i </div> slivki </div>

int main() {
    char **s, itterator[1];
    int result = 0;

    do {
        s = calloc(1, sizeof(char *));
        *s = calloc(1, sizeof(char) * SIZE_OF_STR);

        fputs(">> Type string or 0 to exit: \n", stdout);
        fgets(*s, SIZE_OF_STR, stdin);
        if (*s == NULL) {
            fprintf(stdout, "\n>> Input error, press any key to exit\n");
            getchar();
            return EXIT_SUCCESS;
        } else {
            itterator[0] = **s;

            if (**s != '0') {
                fprintf(stdout, "\n\n<< Input: %s<< Address: %p\n", *s, &*s);
                result = (int) div_format(s);
                fputs("\n\n", stdout);

                free(s);
                free(*s);
            }
        }
    } while (itterator[0] != '0');

    return result;
}

char **div_format(char **s) {
    char *str = *s, **tags, **texts, *out;
    char textholder[15] = "{{textholder}}";
    int i = 0, j = 0, p = 0;
    bool checked = false;

    tags = (char **) calloc(SIZE_OF_STR, sizeof(char *));
    texts = (char **) calloc(SIZE_OF_STR, sizeof(char *));
    out = (char *) calloc(SIZE_OF_ARR_COL, sizeof(char));

    for (int l = 0; l < SIZE_OF_STR; ++l) {
        tags[l] = (char *) calloc(1, sizeof(char) * SIZE_OF_ARR_COL);
        texts[l] = (char *) calloc(1, sizeof(char) * SIZE_OF_ARR_COL);
    }

    while (str[i] != '\0') {
        if (str[i] == ' ' && checked == false) {
            while (str[i] == ' ') i++;
            checked = true;
        }
        if (str[i] == '<') {
            int k = 0;
            while (str[i] != '>' && str[i] != '\0' && str[i] != '\n') {
                if (k == 0) {
                    tags[j][k] = '\n';
                    k++;
                } else {
                    if (k != 1 && str[i] == '<') {
                        k++;
                        break;
                    }
                    tags[j][k] = str[i];
                    if (str[i + 1] == '>') {
                        tags[j][k + 1] = str[i + 1];
                    }
                    i++;
                    k++;
                }
            }
            j++;
        } else {
            int k = 0;
            while ((k == 0 || str[i] != ' ') && str[i] != '\0') {
                if (str[i] != '\n')
                    texts[p][k] = str[i];
                else {
                    p--;
                    break;
                }
                i++;
                k++;
            }
            if (j != 0)
                strcat(tags[j - 1], textholder);
            p++;
        }
        i++;
    }

    fputs("\n", stdout);
    for (int m = 0; m < j; ++m) {
        fprintf(stdout, "<< Tags: %s\tAdress: %p\n", tags[m], &tags[m]);
        strcat(out, tags[m]);
    }
    fputs("\n", stdout);
    for (int n = 0; n < p; ++n) {
        fprintf(stdout, "<< Texts: %s\tAdress: %p\n", texts[n], &texts[n]);
    }

    fprintf(stdout, "\n<< Formatted input: %s\n<< Formatted address: %p\n<< Length: %d\n", out, &out, i);

    for (int w = 0; w < SIZE_OF_STR; ++w) {
        free(texts[w]);
        free(tags[w]);
    }

    free(str);
    free(texts);
    free(tags);
    free(out);
    free(s);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

В комментариях содерится проверочная фраза. Проблема в том, что если просто вводить проверочную фразу, то всё нормально. Но если ввести её дважды(то есть, чтобы было так: `<div> cheburashka <div> pozdno el kofe i </div> slivki </div><div> cheburashka <div> pozdno el kofe i </div> slivki </div>`), то программа вылетает. 
Если убрать все `free()` функции `div_format()`, то можно сколь угодно копипастить, не вылетет. Проблема явно связано с memory management.

Так же, буду рад, если укажете на программные ошибки. Спасибо.

P.S. Ошибка пропала, при перерасчёте констант.

Comment: `free(s);  free(*s);` UB точно.

Comment: @pavel согласен, но все же не корень проблемы

Comment: У Вас 2 раза free одной и той же памяти. Один в конце `div_format(char **s)` (free(s)), а другой в main после вызова `div_format(s);` тоже free(s)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут двуе ошибки

1.
как было сказано выше в коментариях - происходит двойное освобождение s и *s. второе освобождение стоит убрать из div_format()

```
//free(str);
free(texts);
free(tags);
free(out);
//free(s);
```

2.
Здесь перепутаны константы. В начале функции div_format() сначала выделяеться массив указателей на строки, а потом в цикле выделяютьяс сами строки.

Полагаю что должно быть SIZE_OF_ARR_COL строк, и каждая строка должна быть размером SIZE_OF_STR.

А в Вашем исходном коде выделяеться SIZE_OF_STR (1024) строк длиной SIZE_OF_ARR_COL (128) каждая. Программа судя по всему вылетает, когда происходит попытка записать строку длиннее 128 символов (так для строк выделено памяти по 128 символов)

Если поменять местами константы, то все работает без segfault:

```
//tags = (char **) calloc(SIZE_OF_STR, sizeof(char *));
//texts = (char **) calloc(SIZE_OF_STR, sizeof(char *));
//out = (char *) calloc(SIZE_OF_ARR_COL, sizeof(char)); 
tags = (char **) calloc(SIZE_OF_ARR_COL, sizeof(char *));
texts = (char **) calloc(SIZE_OF_ARR_COL, sizeof(char *));
out = (char *) calloc(SIZE_OF_STR, sizeof(char));         

//for (int l = 0; l < SIZE_OF_STR; ++l) {
//    tags[l] = (char *) calloc(1, sizeof(char) * SIZE_OF_ARR_COL);
//    texts[l] = (char *) calloc(1, sizeof(char) * SIZE_OF_ARR_COL);
//}                                                                 
for (int l = 0; l < SIZE_OF_ARR_COL; ++l) {                         
    tags[l] = (char *) calloc(1, sizeof(char) * SIZE_OF_STR);       
    texts[l] = (char *) calloc(1, sizeof(char) * SIZE_OF_STR);      
}                                                                   

...
//for (int w = 0; w < SIZE_OF_STR; ++w) {
//    free(texts[w]);
//    free(tags[w]);
//}    
for (int w = 0; w < SIZE_OF_ARR_COL; ++w) {
    free(texts[w]);
    free(tags[w]);
}

...
//free(str);
free(texts);
free(tags);
free(out);
//free(s);
```

PS

Так же следует поменять порядок освобождения массива s:

```
free(*s);
free(s);
```

(сначала освобождаеться строка, а затем указатель на строку). Иначе есть риск seg fault в этом месте.

Comment: Основная ошибка у ТС это 2 раза free на память, которую он получает в main вот тут -- `do {
        s = calloc(1, sizeof(char *)); ...`

Comment: да, согласен, и эта тоже. сейчас исправлю основной ответ.

Comment: Спасибо, я внёс все и изменения и всё работает